# C++: Is it safe to delete post-increment operator on custom iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, standards, std

According to the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator), the requirement of a forward iterator is that it supports the post-increment operator (i.e. `iterator operator++(int)` and

I am wondering if it's safe to `disallow` this operation on a custom forward iterator, i.e.

```
custom_iterator operator++(int) = delete; // disallow post-increment, i.e. it++
custom_iterator operator++() { ... } // we only define pre-increment, i.e. ++it
```

and assume that STL will never call `it++` on such a custom iterator `it`, when it is passed as an argument to a STL generic algorithm such as `copy`, `sort`, `fill` etc.?

A quote from the official C++11 standard regarding this matter would be the most useful one, but answers such as "most implementation do this and that" are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All iterators must be both pre- and post-incrementable.  This is part of the requirements for both input and output iterators.  See C++11 §24.2[iterator.requirements] Tables 107 and 108.  It's rather hard to quote the tables, but in both tables, the expression `++r` and `r++` must be valid for an iterator `r`.

So, no.  If you are implementing a new iterator type, instances of that type must be both pre- and post-incrementable, and all STL algorithms and any other functions that take iterators may assume post-incrementability.

Because iterators must also be copy constructible, it is generally trivial to implement the postincrement operator in terms of the preincrement operator.  For example,

```
MyIterator operator++(int)
{
    MyIterator original(*this);
    ++*this;
    return original;
}
```

Comment: On the other hand, if ones does not implement post-increment, the compiler will give an error if that operator is required.  So while a custom iterator without post-increment should not be billed as "STL compatible", it will actually work fine with a number of algorithms anyway.  +1 for the suggestion of how to implement post-increment in terms of pre-increment.